# Really slow or stuck pos loading with large number of product

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have installed odoo on 'Bitnami Launchpad for AWS Cloud'. In my database there are more then 830000 product. when I start POS it loads very slowly during product load, after some time it crash and give error : 'XmlHttpRequestError Proxy Error' (, /web/dataset/search_read: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http')

What is the solution to optimize it to load faster.

Comment: You should try this. https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/pos_cache/  or https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/pos_data_cache/